# Cast Iron Adapter vs http adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Im trying to find out what does the cast iron adapter give you that you cant achieve with a regular http adapter, they seem to be the same.

Cant find any documentation that gives any specific additional functionality..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cast Iron adapter offers nothing that can't be achieved with an HTTP Adapter. I think it just makes it a bit more convenient to add a header or something along those lines.